# How to search and match pattern to get a value in ansible

Tags: regex, split, ansible

My variable `info` has below value. (Actual case has huge data).

I am trying to search for specific word `XYZ_data_001` and get the size information, which is after the pattern `physical disk,`

```
XYZ_data_001         file system device, special, dsync off, directio on, physical disk, 16384.00 MB, Free: 0.00 MB      2         0      6       0  8388607
XYZ_data_002         file system device, special, dsync off, directio on, physical disk, 16384.00 MB, Free: 0.00 MB      2         0     13       0  8388607
```

here is what is tried

```
    - name: Print size
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "{{ info | regex_search('XYZ_data_001(.+)') | split('physical disk,') | last }}"
```

this will give me below output

```
ok: [testhost] => {
    "msg": " 16384.00 MB, Free: 0.00 MB      2         0      6       0  8388607 "
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
{{ info | regex_search('XYZ_data_001\\b.*physical disk,\\s*(\\d[\\d.]*)', '\\1') }}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xJS55H/1).

*Details*:

- `XYZ_data_001` - a `XYZ_data_001` string
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `.*` - any text (any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible)
- `physical disk,` - a literal string
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(\d[\d.]*)` - Group 1 (`\1`): a digit and then zero or more digits or dots.

Comment: As an addition, I am trying to divide the Value by 1024. But it works with below conversion.
```
 trim | join('.') | float / 1024
``` 
anything I can improve here

Answer (score 1):

There are two filters in the collection [*Community.General*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/index.html) that will help you to create [dictionaries](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/docsite/filter_guide_abstract_informations_dictionaries.html#dictionaries) from the *info*.

1. Split the lines, [*split*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#manipulating-strings) and [*trim*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.trim) the items, and use the filter [*community.general.dict*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/docsite/filter_guide_abstract_informations_dictionaries.html#dictionaries) to create the list of dictionaries

```yaml
  info_dict1: "{{ info.splitlines()|
                  map('split', ',')|
                  map('map', 'trim')|
                  map('zip', ['dev', 'spec', 'dsync', 'dir', 'disk', 'size', 'free'])|
                  map('map', 'reverse')|
                  map('community.general.dict') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  info_dict1:
  - dev: XYZ_data_001         file system device
    dir: directio on
    disk: physical disk
    dsync: dsync off
    free: 'Free: 0.00 MB      2         0      6       0  8388607'
    size: 16384.00 MB
    spec: special
  - dev: XYZ_data_002         file system device
    dir: directio on
    disk: physical disk
    dsync: dsync off
    free: 'Free: 0.00 MB      2         0     13       0  8388607'
    size: 16384.00 MB
    spec: special
```

2. Split the attribute *dev* and use the filter [*community.general.dict_kv*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/docsite/filter_guide_abstract_informations_dictionaries.html#dictionaries) to  create the list of dictionaries with the attribute *device*

```yaml
  info_dev: "{{ info_dict1|
                map(attribute='dev')|
                map('split')|
                map('first')|
                map('community.general.dict_kv', 'device') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  info_dev:
  - device: XYZ_data_001
  - device: XYZ_data_002
```

Combine the dictionaries

```yaml
  info_dict2: "{{ info_dict1|zip(info_dev)|map('combine') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  info_dict2:
  - dev: XYZ_data_001         file system device
    device: XYZ_data_001
    dir: directio on
    disk: physical disk
    dsync: dsync off
    free: 'Free: 0.00 MB      2         0      6       0  8388607'
    size: 16384.00 MB
    spec: special
  - dev: XYZ_data_002         file system device
    device: XYZ_data_002
    dir: directio on
    disk: physical disk
    dsync: dsync off
    free: 'Free: 0.00 MB      2         0     13       0  8388607'
    size: 16384.00 MB
    spec: special
```

This way you can add other attributes if needed.

---

Q: ***"Search for specific word `XYZ_data_001` and get the `size`."***

A: Create a dictionary *device_size*

```yaml
  device_size: "{{ info_dict2|items2dict(key_name='device', value_name='size') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  device_size:
    XYZ_data_001: 16384.00 MB
    XYZ_data_002: 16384.00 MB
```

Search the dictionary

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "Size of XYZ_data_001 is {{ device_size.XYZ_data_001 }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: Size of XYZ_data_001 is 16384.00 MB
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    info: |
      XYZ_data_001         file system device, special, dsync off, directio on, physical disk, 16384.00 MB, Free: 0.00 MB      2         0      6       0  8388607
      XYZ_data_002         file system device, special, dsync off, directio on, physical disk, 16384.00 MB, Free: 0.00 MB      2         0     13       0  8388607

    info_dict1: "{{ info.splitlines()|
                    map('split', ',')|
                    map('map', 'trim')|
                    map('zip', ['dev', 'spec', 'dsync', 'dir', 'disk', 'size', 'free'])|
                    map('map', 'reverse')|
                    map('community.general.dict') }}"

    info_dev: "{{ info_dict1|
                  map(attribute='dev')|
                  map('split')|
                  map('first')|
                  map('community.general.dict_kv', 'device') }}"

    info_dict2: "{{ info_dict1|zip(info_dev)|map('combine') }}"

    device_size: "{{ info_dict2|items2dict(key_name='device', value_name='size') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: info_dict1
    - debug:
        var: info_dev
    - debug:
        var: info_dict2
    - debug:
        var: device_size
    - debug:
        msg: "Size of XYZ_data_001 is {{ device_size.XYZ_data_001 }}"
```